# How can I change scheduling time at run time

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I'm trying to display a popup window at a time specified by the user? The popup only shows up on the precoded time, so I tried this. Now I'm receiving an error saying: `int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'`

```
class MainApp(MDApp):
    hour = NumericProperty(None, allowenone=True)
    minute = NumericProperty(None, allowenone=True)

    def build(self):
        # calling the service
        if platform == "android":
            from android import AndroidService
            service = AndroidService("my pong service", "running")
            service.start("service started")
            self.service = service

        schedule.every().day.at(f'{int(self.hour)}:{int(self.minute)}').do(self.mantraPop_message)
        #schedule.every().day.at(str(0) + str(self.hour) + ":" + str(self.minute)).do(self.show_notification)
        Clock.schedule_interval(lambda dt: schedule.run_pending(), 1)
        return MainScreen()

    def show_timepicker(self):
        picker = MDTimePicker()
        picker.bind(time=self.got_time)
        picker.open()

    def got_time(self, picker_widget, time):
        self.hour = time.hour
        self.minute = time.minute
        print(f'{int(self.hour)}:{int(self.minute)}')
```

Answer (score 1):

`schedule.every().day.at(f'{int(self.hour)}:{int(self.minute)}').do(self.mantraPop_message)` should be placed in `def got_time():` so that it will call schedule every time that the time is set. `self.hour` can also be empty now. What was happening before was that when the app runs, the scheduling begins and cannot be updated so now, the scheduling only begins when the time has been set by the user.